# How do i send function arguments into an dictionary and then json?

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I'm creating a discord bot. It's needed to send command arguments into dictionary and then json. First as key and folowing as array.

BUT! It sends only second and third arguments.

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def next(ctx,name,time):
    author = ctx.message.author
    #role authentification
    if "561139623250755585" in [y.id for y in author.roles]:
            rere = time + ' ' + date
            db = dict(name = rere)
            with open("time.json" , "a") as file:
                json.dump(db, file)
            with open("time.json" , "r") as fil:
                Dec = json.load(fil)
                Out = Dec[name]
                await client.say(Out)
    else:
        with open("time.json" , "r") as file:
            Dec = json.load(file)
            Out = Dec[name]
            await client.say(Out)
```

As you an see in the code,it must turn three arguments into dict. BUT! it seems like python passes it here `db = dict(name = rere)` and uses it like key here `Out = Dec[name]`
With input `/next gg gg gg` it returns into json `{"name":'gg gg'}`
and this error in the console `Out = Dec[name]
KeyError: 'gg'`
How to fix it?

Comment: The longer I look at your code, the less sense it makes. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

When using the `dict` function to create a dictionary, the keyword argument will be transformed into the keyword. For example, if you did like this `dict(username=rere)` you would get `{ 'username': 'gg gg' }`.

To get the content of the `name` variable, you can do like this:

```
db = {}
db[name] = rere
```

or

```
db = { name: rere }
```

In both cases, the content of the variable `name` will be used as key in the dictionary.